# How to Convert mulfiple files using ffmpeg

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, convert

I need to convert 1000 files from .flv to mp4. 
I organized 10 folders with 100 items each. 
I have been using the following command in each file:

Root@root:~/1/2/3/4$ ffmpeg -i 1.flv -codec copy 1.mp4
...(all the way through 100)
Root@root:~/1/2/3/4$ ffmpeg -i 100.flv -codec copy 100.mp4 
and So on.

It has been working perfectly. The mp4 items get converted in less than a second, but, I wanted to do the whole 100 items at once.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: You can also concatenate them into a single video, if you prefer that.

Comment: How can you do that?

Comment: See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for i in {1..100} ; do ffmpeg -i $i.flv -codec copy $i.mp4 ; done
```

Comment: It worked for 2 files, I just did what you suggested, I wanted to do two first to test.

for i in {115..116} ; do ffmpeg -i $i.flv -codec copy $i.mp4 ; done. 

I will now to the other 702 that I have left. 

Thank you very much!